# Visual Studio 2022 keeps crashing and locking the system

Tags: visual-studio, crash, freeze, visual-studio-2022

I got a new laptop for Christmas, upto date with Windows 10.

Installed Visual Studio 2022 and so far it's been crashing every day several times a day. It could be either on the coding screen, the design view, or simply in a menu.

It just freezes the whole screen and the mouse stops and no keyboard responses work. I have to turn off the laptop via the power button.

It's happened about 15-20 times in the last few days. Any ideas?

It's Windows 10 Home, and 4GB RAM. No other programs crash it's only Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance
Mark.

Comment: Check for driver updates, run a memory test. It could be VS is stressing the system more than anything else you've installed and thus showing up problems. Given it is a new laptop I would suspect a hardware issue.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for your reply. I checked all that and it was still freezing the system and I couldn't even do basic coding before it froze. I have since installed the previous version, Visual Studio 2019 and not had a single problem! Am making exactly the same program I was coding in vs2022 (in C#) and not had a single freeze or crash! So.. am going to continue using VS2019.

Comment: I didn't think new laptops came with less than 8GB RAM these days? :) You may struggle with only 4GB. VS2022 is now 64bit and will use more resources. What is your memory usage and CPU usage when you get the crashes? Do you have any extensions installed in VS? What size projects are you working on?

Comment: I've got same problem and started also about 3 weeks ago. Just crash on typing (C#). Done memory ect. test and no problemo. Downgrading back to VS2019....

Comment: My vs is doing the same thing with my solution. 8 fairly small projs, one of which contains typescript spa. all projs contain a dockerfile. Running on a really beefy workstation.

Comment: I used to leave my laptop with the back end and front end projects in VS2022 open from one day to another and I always got a blue screen of death with the `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` stop code in the middle of the night; sometimes during development too. Both projects had node processes running, but my laptop is pretty capable. I switched back to VS2019 and never had this problem again. Btw, I maintain everything up to date, every week. I suggest everyone go back to VS2019.

Answer (score 6):

I went back to VS 2019. No issues now.

Comment: You also have Windows 10 home with 4GB ram?

Comment: It happens with Windows 11 32 GB ram.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too and I solved changing the Visual Studio font.

Go to Tools->Options->Font and colors and change the default *Cascade Mono* font to *Consoles*

After that change zero crashes.

Comment: I have no idea why this would work, but it does. Thanks!

Comment: Try this first, friends! We had recently upgraded Windows to Server 2016 (we have to use a shared machine). Cascade Mono is not supported on Server 2016.

Answer (score 3):

It may be the antivirus. Following [Eliot Jones'](https://eliot-jones.com/2022/2/visual-studio-2022-freeze-debug) solution to exclude `VsDebugConsole.exe` worked for me:

Open the *Windows Security* app, then go to *Virus & threat protection* > Virus & threat protection settings *Manage Settings* > Exclusions *Add or remove exclusions* > *Add an exclusion*

Answer (score 3):

For some time now, my entire computer freezes when opening solution. In my case it seems to be caused by a corrupted `.vs` directory. Deleting this folder fixed the problem. Problems like these never happened in **VS2019**, I only started noticing them since I switched to **VS2022**.

Answer (score 1):

i just using repair system visual studio installer, maybe too much extension installed impacted to you system performance, i do had 16gb , but after repair the vs22 never crash or freeze again

Comment: It is also happening to me,VS 2022 freeze , lock, i need to kill it in task manager

Comment: Fresh install right out-of-the-box, VS 2022 locks up frequently (5-10 times per hour or more, depending on usage). .NET 6, 24GB RAM, SSD with lots of space, Intel I5.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worded for me.
[Turn off hardware graphics acceleration to switch to software rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/ide/performance-crash-issue).
To do this, follow these steps:

1. In Visual Studio, click Tools > Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, clear the Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance check box. (Refer to the following screenshot for this step.)
3. Clear the Use hardware graphics acceleration if available check box to prevent the use of hardware graphics acceleration.
4. Select or clear the Enable rich client visual experience check box to make sure that rich visuals are always on or off, respectively. When this check box is selected, rich visuals are used independent of the computer environment. For example, rich visuals are used when you run Visual Studio locally on a rich client and over remote desktop.